# Python web scraping with login

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, request

I'm trying to login through a site that is password protected in order to get access to a protected page, i have the email and password names along with the csrf-token.But when i try to access the protected page it doesnt allow me and redirects me back to the login.Any help would be awesome!The site im trying to access is.

https://www.usertesting.com/users/sign_in

```
import requests
from lxml import html

session_requests = requests.session()

login_url = "https://www.usertesting.com/users/sign_in"
result = session_requests.get(login_url)

tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//meta[@name='csrf-token']/@content")))[0]

userInfo = {
    "user[email]": "email", 
    "user[password]": "password", 
    "csrf-token": authenticity_token
}

result = session_requests.post(
    login_url, 
    data = userInfo, 
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)

url = 'https://www.usertesting.com/my_dashboard'

result = session_requests.get(
    url, 
    headers = dict(referer = url)
)

print result.content
```

Comment: If you inspect the post data you'll see it's more than 3 inputs (6)  you propably need all of tem. Also you may have to include 'User-Agent' and 'Referer' in `headers`

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at this https://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/ for the answer you're looking for. Summarizing, you're going to need to inspect the web page and before you begin your full scraping program you should write another function that will enter the username, password, then enter the site. After that completes, begin the full scripting.

Comment: Ah, I see. What does `print result.content` return after you execute it? (I am not a member of the site so I cannot continue forward testing

Comment: it returns the html for the sign in page, so im figuring im getting redirected to that page